# pasting in vba data

Tags: excel, vba

[image worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVsNL.jpg)I am setting up sheet with hotels details and column "D" has hospitals that are close by eg PMH,SCGH,FSH. What i am trying to do is search column "D" based on a cell value on same sheet. I have code below but it will only do what i want if the cells in column"D" are single entry eg pmh. I need to be able to search all the cells in Column "D" for any instance of the text.

Many Thanks for any assistance

```
`Option Explicit
Sub finddata()
Dim hospitalname As String
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Sheets("Results").Range("A4:D100").ClearContents

Sheets("Main").Select
hospitalname = Sheets("Main").Range("g3").Value
finalrow = Sheets("Main").Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To finalrow
    If Cells(i, 4) = hospitalname Then
    Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 4)).Copy
    Sheets("Results").Range("A4").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial       xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
    End If
Next i

Sheets("Main").Range("g3").Select

End Sub
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two simplest ways to do this would be

1. Using the `Like` operator:

   ```
   If Cells(i, 4).Value Like "*" & hospitalname & "*" Then
   ```

   This method has the drawback that a hospital name of, for instance, `PMH` might be matched against another one such as `SPMH`.
2. Using the `InStr` function:

   ```
   If Instr("," & Cells(i, 4).Value & ",", "," & hospitalname & ",") > 0 Then
   ```

   In this line, I "wrap" both the cell being looked at, and the value being searched for, within commas so it ends up searching for the string (for instance) `",PMH,"` within the string `",PMH,SCGH,FSH,"`.  `InStr` will return the character position at which a match occurs, or zero if no match is found.  So testing for `> 0` is testing whether a match occurred.